# Rails link_to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do the exact same thing as the following line of code does

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
```

But instead of using a button, I need a link.
Can someone post an equivalent link_to call?

Comment: Why not just read [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and figure out how a `link_to` call works?

Comment: Way to be helpful :|

Comment: Well to be honest, it didn't seem like you put much effort into figuring the problem out yourself. The documentation pretty clearly shows how a `link_to` call is made.

Comment: [This set of documents](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) provides better examples on `link_to`'s usage.

Comment: I did go through the link_to documentation before posting the comment. I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to make it looks like a button. To do so, include [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and update your code like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Add to Cart', "javascript:postData(#{product.id});", :class => "btn btn-default" %>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function postData(productId){
    $.post("/line_items, { product_id: productId } );
  }
</script>
```

More about **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**

Comment: This sends a GET request to line_items_path. The button sends a POST request.
Or is it not possible to send a POST request by clicking a link?